# How can I use a variable in String.fromCharCode()?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the code below to convert the unicode into a string but have no luck, please help?

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var message = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    message += str.charCodeAt(i) + " ";
  }
  message = message.split(" ").filter(Boolean).join(",");
  return String.fromCharCode(message);
}
console.log(rot13("Hello World"))
```

Comment: fromCharCode("1,1,1,1") is not the same thing as  fromCharCode(1,1,1,1)

Comment: @epascarello what if i made it an array?

Comment: @ajhernandez95 an Array also ain't a number. `String.fromCharCode()` takes multiple arguments, each one of them being a single charCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromCharCode("1,1,1,1")` is not the same thing as `fromCharCode(1,1,1,1)` you need to use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with an array.

```js
function rot13(str) {
  var message = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    message += str.charCodeAt(i) + " ";
  }
  message = message.split(" ").filter(Boolean);
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, message);
}
console.log(rot13("Hello World"))
```

Comment: So if i had an array instead of a string would i put Array in the apply method?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this: 
http://buildingonmud.blogspot.com/2009/06/convert-string-to-unicode-in-javascript.html

```js
function toUnicode(theString) {
  var unicodeString = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    var theUnicode = theString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();

    while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
      theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
    }

    theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
    unicodeString += theUnicode;
  }

  return unicodeString;
}

console.log(toUnicode("Hello World"));
```